# Looking for Full Screen Web-Browser in Vizio or Samsung TV's

Tags: tv, google-tv

I see that Google TV, inside Sony, has a Chrome browser.

Is the same thing possible inside Vizio, or Samsung, or any other TV? The 42" Vizio is $499 at Costco, and the Sony with Google TV is $999.

We're looking at a buch of these TV's that have build in Wi-Fi, to place around the office as Big Dashboards, and I don't want to have a computer attached to get web content on the screen. It's my understanding that both Samsung Apps, and Vizio Apps, use Yahoo Widgets as their ap engine.

Anyone know of a way to get a full screen browser going, without attaching a computer?

We thought of attaching an Apple TV, which can be jailbroken, but that is just another piece of equipment to lose, break, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Every model will be different... need more specifics... and... off topic!

Comment: this was migrated here - to super user by an admin - so i'm sorry that I get penalized because someone moved it to the wrong place. My is my understanding. At the end of the day I'm trying to get full screen browser to show our web content - without adding another device to the television.

Answer (score 0):

Google is compatible with any TV with an HDMI port so your Visio or Samsung will work with it. 
I think the Sony has Google TV built in ( can't be certain without Model) whereas with the others you have to get something like the Logitech review( comparable to the apple TV)